# Is it possible to use desktop icon badges to show count of unread messages in Swing Java 8?

Tags: java, swing, java-8, taskbar, badge

Now I use custom method to draw on the existing icon my own badge but I can't draw outside of the origin icon dimension.
I have found in Java 9 class Taskbar with badges support. Is it possible to do something similar in Java 8?

Badge is a small mark that notifies the user that there is some new activity in the app. For example:

[image: badge]

Comment: I don't know what a "badge" is, but no you can't draw outside the bounds of an Icon. Just make your Icon bigger and make parts of it transparent.

Comment: @camickr I assume that the OP relates to those [icon modifications](https://images.ctfassets.net/3cttzl4i3k1h/32XWW0tPb2AQGgIIuiOAuI/67c414e15ad117e16fbbeced8d507119/app-badges.png?w=1400&h=600&q=80&fm=&f=&fit=fill) which you often see on phones.

Comment: Maybe you can use [Compound Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/compound-icon/).